# How to add a uuid primary key to existing table without id column

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Other than dropping and recreating a table, how can I add a primary key id column of type uuid to a table that was created without an id field - a join table?

I tried:

```
add_column :organizations_users, :id, :uuid, primary_key: true
```

but the column doesn't get set as a primary key.

Looking at the **new_column_definition** ActiveRecord method, the code above should work:

```
column.primary_key = type == :primary_key || options[:primary_key]
```

I must be having a brain fart...

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but if anyone comes across it, this worked for me in Rails 5.2. I was already using UUIDs for primary key :id columns in other tables, so you might need to set that up first if you're not.

```
def change
  add_column :products_questions, :id, :uuid, primary_key: true, default: -> { "gen_random_uuid()" }
end
```